# Plotting Data using matplotlib from a 2D array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of lists in python having the following simple structure

```
Data=[
        [2,4,3,7,8],
        [4,5,7,8,3],
        ......and so on
     ]
```

Now I want to plot a graph between `Data[0]` and `Data[i] for 1<=i<len(Data)` where each graph appears after a gap of 2 seconds. I wrote the following code for the above task

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(1,len(Data)):
        plt.plot(Y[0],Y[i],'ro')
        plt.show()
        time.sleep(2)
        plt.close()
```

However, the code doesn't seem to work and each figure has to be closed manually for the next one to appear. Where am I going wrong. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.show()` can take a single argument, `block`, that allows you to set the call to be nonblocking.

The code you have will work, if you add this argument.

replace 
`plt.show()` with `plt.show(block=False)`

and you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: i) I mean its not necessarily 2 sec's. It could be 10 or 20. I just wanted to avoid the hard work of closing each window again and again.
ii) Your method shows all the graphs almost simultaneously...this is not the final functionality I wanted. Some altogether different way of doing it?
iii) And yes the graphs show what I want. I just want to do some data analysis and observe the dependency of one value over different features.

Comment: @alphacentauri Good catch, sorry about that. I've edited my answer to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to cycle through the graphs every `x` seconds you could turn interactive plotting on via `ion()`

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

Data=[
        [2,4,3,7,8],
        [4,5,7,8,3],
        ... and so on 
     ]

for i in range(1,len(Data)):
        plt.plot(Data[0],Data[i],'ro')
        plt.draw()
        time.sleep(2)
        plt.close()
```